# Understanding better a sort algorithm - Looking for a reference about it

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I am trying to understanding a little better the sort algorithm showed below and I not succeeding in it and since I am not from the computer area I do not know if this algorithm in some known one.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int main() {
  int unsorted[100] = {};
  srand (time(NULL));
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    unsorted[i] = rand() % 100;
  }
  int sorted[100] = {};
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    int hi = -1;
    int hiIndex = -1;
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
      if (unsorted[j] > hi) {
        hi = unsorted[j];
        hiIndex = j;
      }
    }
    sorted[i] = hi;
    unsorted[hiIndex] = -1;
  }
}
```

Heres goes the question:

- Is this sort algorithm some classic and known one? If yes, what is it name and where can I find a reference to read about it. In this reference, it would be great if I could find some discussion about the efficiency of this algorithm.
- If it is not a classic sort algorithm I would like to have some help to understanding its logic and again to know about is efficiency.

Comment: Something like `selection sort`.

Answer (score 2):

This is not any classical algorithm but similar to one, which is popularly known as selection sort. In the given code sample on each iteration of the inner loop we look for the highest number in the unsorted array and put it in the ith index in the sorted array and then we make this number -1 in the unsorted array.
For example consider the given array

unsorted: 5, 7, 2, 9, 6
sorted array:

after first iteration of the outer loop: i=0, hi=9, hiIndex=3

unsorted: 5, 7, 2, -1, 6 
sorted: 9

after second iteration of the outer loop: i=1, hi=7, hiIndex=1

unsorted: 5, -1, 2, -1, 6
sorted: 9, 7

You see as wee go on we the list sorted in the descending order in the array sorted.

The time complexity of this algorithm is O(n^2), and this is not a very efficient way of sorting arrays. This algorithm will fail if we have negative numbers in the array, for example the above algorithm cannot sort this list {1,5,-5,7, -9] as -1 is greater than -5 and -9

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a rather simple but inefficient algorithm that makes multiple passes over the input array and moves the highest number it finds into another array. If you're looking for a sorting algorithm, this is very inefficient and uses extra space. You might want to look into something more efficient like [Quick Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) or [Merge Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort).

Answer (score 0):

The sorting algorithm is very similar to **selection sort**. It has the (rather bad) runtime of O(n²).

However, this implementation is even worse than the "normal" one since it works with two arrays: The original one and the sorted one. Usually, selection sort is performed **in-place** (with only one array). This has the benefit that the inner loop can skip the array elements that are already sorted.

Another disadvantage of this implementation is that it doesn't work with negative numbers. But maybe that isn't required here.

Comment: Selection sort has O(n^2) time complexity.